# Jenkins で月をまたいだビルドトリガの設定を記述したい

Tags: jenkins

jenkinsでバッチの自動実行を設定したいです。

**設定例**

```
3/31（金） 22:00 実行 
4/01（土） 02:00 実行
```

曜日は無視していただいて構いません。

上記のように月をまたぐような場合、どのように書けばよいのでしょうか？

参考サイト 
[Jenkins ビルドトリガ（定期的に実行）設定についてのまとめ - Qiita](http://qiita.com/koara-local/items/79cb9c08e77ac9d94b1d)

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/70500

Comment: マルチポスト先もそうですが解決した場合は、こちらでは回答横のチェックマークを選択して承認、向こうでは解決済みにしてください。各投稿先のメンテナンスができないのであればマルチポストは行うべきではありません。

Answer (score 2):

2行で表現すればどうでしょう。

```
# 3/31 22:00
0 22 31 3 *

# 4/1 2:00
0 2 1 4 *
```

Comment: 2行でかけるのですね！ありがとうございます